# How can I get Crystal Reports for VS2010 to install?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Every time I try to install (5 attempts) I get:

> Error 2753. the File "agent.exe.6ED28686_7b19_420c_b255_5b6c1bd2c705" is not marked for installation

I've tried uninstalling, deleting the install folder after installing, clearing out temp files, restarting the machine and making sure I run the setup as administrator but I get this every time. I've even followed some advice about putting the installer files in `c:\cr4vs2010` but to no avail.

The customer I'm developing for has Crystal skills so no other reporting engine will do.

EDIT

Found out about the FLEXnet transformer that fixes the above error. However, on completion of the install I get an error "The operation could not be completed" in a dialog box headed "Visual Studio".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it I think. I now have Crystal Templates.

To fix.

1. Get the Flexera tool at

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=Q207355&sliceId=

1. Run the tool as instructed and install the two msi's using it. I did the VS install first, then the 64-bit runtime.
2. After getting the "The operation could not be completed" error and installing both msi's, open up the Visual Studio Command prompt, ensuring you elect to Run as Administrator.
3. execute the command line `devenv /installvstemplates`. This takes a few minutes.

That fixed it for me.

Comment: great answer! it worked exactly for me. how did you find this solution?